# aws describe instances using jq cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

```
#!/bin/bash
SECURITY_GROUP_ID="$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq -r ' .SecurityGroups[] | select(.IpPermissions[] | .FromPort == 22 and .IpRanges[].CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0") | .GroupId')"
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--filters "Name=network-interface.group-id,Values=${SECURITY_GROUP_ID}" \
| jq -r ".Reservations | .[] | .Instances | .[] | .InstanceId"
```

this is giving empty output with job showing as succeeded. The actual output should be list of all ec2 instances with security groups meeting the IpPermissions criteria. Can anyone correct this script?
Thanks

Comment: You didn't provide any JSON output from the `aws` calls, so it's hard to figure out where the `jq` calls detour, but generally speaking, using iterators (as in `.IpPermissions[]` or `.IpRanges[]`) within a `select` clause without an aggregator such as `all` or `any` is *usually* not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using ‘for’ loop in the script and describe the instances using filter and query option inside ‘for’ loop. So it will take the output from describe security groups and used it as variable in ‘for’ loop to query instances as given below.
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=network-interface.group-id,Values=$sg --query …………

this worked well if you want to list instances with particular security group ids

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
SECURITY_GROUP_ID="$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq -r ' .SecurityGroups[] | select(.IpPermissions[] | .FromPort == 22 and .IpRanges[].CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0") | .GroupId')"
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--filters "Name=instance.group-id,Values=`echo -n $SECURITY_GROUP_ID | tr '\n' ','`" \
| jq -r ".Reservations | .[] | .Instances | .[] | .InstanceId"
```

Comment: Hi thank you for correcting the script. I tried with this still it is giving an empty output.

Comment: After running above script, the list of all instance ids which are in that particular security group should be displayed in output. But its giving an empty output and showing as job succeeded